# R's httr package, call GET with an argument

Tags: r, httr

Using httr, how would i perform the equivalent of

```
curl -XGET 'http://foo/bar/_search?pretty' -d '{
   "query": {
        "filtered": {
              ...
          }
      }
   }'
```

(and the response is JSON encoded).

The following failed

```
f <- GET("http://foo/bar/_search",query=list(Q))
```

where Q is the above JSON parameter passed after -d.

thank you

Comment: I believe `httr::GET` ignores body requests. Looks like you are using Elasticsearch? If so, you may be interested in https://github.com/ropensci/elastic